# How do I call functions in a C program?

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a dice game with the following rules:

1. You roll three dice
2. If you roll and each die is 6, you win 100kr
3. If you roll and each die is identical (but not 6), you win 50kr
4. If you roll and two dies are identical, you win 10 kr
5. The player must bet at least 10kr each turn to play
6. If the player wins, they are asked if they want to play again
7. When the player's money is less than 10kr, the player is told that they can no longer play.

I've been able to this, but now I have to run this by calling a function.  I've gotten stuck at this point - my code is below, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int rolling(int dice1, int dice2, int dice3, int moneyinput, char keep_rolling ); // prototype
keep_rolling = 'y';

int main()
{
    int d1, d2, d3, money, r;
    char keep_rolling = 'n';
    money = 100;
    r = rolling(d1, d2, d3, money,keep_rolling);
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    printf("welcome to the game! \n \n");

    //gameroll
    printf("1.it cost you 10kr to play \n");
    printf("2.if all the dicies are sixes you win 100kr \n");
    printf("3. if all the dicies are alike except number (6) you win 50kr \n");
    printf("4. if you get at least two alike you 1 \n");
    printf("5. otherwise you win nothing\n");

    printf("you have %d kr, if you wnat to play press (n) \n\n", money);
    fflush(stdin);
    keep_rolling = ((getchar()));
    d1 = (rand() % 6 + 1);
    d2 = (rand() % 6 + 1);
    d3 = (rand() % 6 + 1);


}

int rolling(int dice1, int dice2, int dice3, int moneyinput, char keep_rolling) // def my function 
{
    keep_rolling = 'y';
    do {
        dice1 = (rand() % 6 + 1);
        dice2 = (rand() % 6 + 1);// from 1 to 6
        dice3 = (rand() % 6 + 1);

        if (moneyinput < 10)
        {
            printf("you do not have enough money \n");
            break; // exit the program
        }
        moneyinput -= 10;
        if (dice1 == 6 && dice2 == 6 & dice3 == 6)
        {
            printf("you have won 100\n ");
            moneyinput += 90;
        }
        else if (dice1 == dice2 == dice3)
        {
            printf("you have won 50kr \n");
            moneyinput += 40;
        }
        else if (dice1 == dice2 || dice1 == dice3 || dice2 == dice3)
        {
            printf("you have won 10kr \n");
            moneyinput += 10;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Sorry! you have lost. god luck next time \n");
        }
    } while (keep_rolling == 'y');
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This will not compile.

Comment: Why do you call `rolling` before you even welcome the user?

Comment: How about using some proper English and punctuation?

Comment: @xxbbcc I've edited the post for him - he just needs to accept the changes.

Comment: @tonysdg Thank you, that's nice of you.

Comment: `else if (dice1 == dice2 == dice3)` won't do what you want. It should be `else if (dice1 == dice2 && dice2 == dice3)`

Comment: the posted code contains several problems.  Always compile with all warnings enabled (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ) then fix those warnings.   Note: if you fix the warnings, then you will not need that `#pragma` statement (which is not even recognized (and therefore ignored) in gcc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your question to user into the rolling function. Your main function does not operate independent for your rolling function.

Also you have some logic errors in your if statements that will make your result be different then what you desire.

```
if (dice1 == 6 && dice2 == 6 & dice3 == 6)
```

should be

```
if (dice1 == 6 && dice2 == 6 && dice3 == 6)
```

And

```
else if (dice1 == dice2 == dice3)
```

should be

```
else if (dice1 == dice2 && dice2 == dice3)
```

Beyond that you also need to make a return from the rolling function.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
It's written to run on a Linux terminal so it uses fgets() for user input.
The idea is to just have a loop in main() that continues to run until the user wants to stop or runs out of money. In this loop call your dice rolling function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int diceRoll(int moneyinput);

int diceRoll(int moneyinput)
{
    int dice1 = (rand() % 6 + 1);
    int dice2 = (rand() % 6 + 1);// from 1 to 6
    int dice3 = (rand() % 6 + 1);

    moneyinput -= 10;
    if (dice1 == 6 && dice2 == 6 && dice3 == 6)
    {
        printf("you have won 100\n ");
        moneyinput += 90;
    }
    else if (dice1 == dice2 && dice2 == dice3)
    {
        printf("you have won 50kr \n");
        moneyinput += 40;
    }
    else if (dice1 == dice2 || dice1 == dice3 || dice2 == dice3)
    {
        printf("you have won 10kr \n");
        moneyinput += 10;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Sorry! you have lost. good luck next time \n");
    }
    return( moneyinput);
}


int main()
{
    int money = 100;
    char choice[2];

    srand((int)time(NULL));

    printf("welcome to the game! \n \n");

    printf("1.it cost you 10kr to play \n");
    printf("2.if all the dicies are sixes you win 100kr \n");
    printf("3. if all the dicies are alike except number (6) you win 50kr \n");
    printf("4. if you get at least two alike you 1 \n");
    printf("5. otherwise you win nothing\n");

    do
    {
        printf("you have %d kr, if you want to play press (y): ", money);
        fgets( choice, sizeof(choice)+1, stdin );   // read a char then LF

        if( 'y' == choice[0] )
        {
            money = diceRoll( money );
        }
    }while( (money >= 10) && choice[0] == 'y' );

    printf("Quitting game with %dkr!\n", money);

}
```